# Easy way to change to parent dir of a buffer?

Tags: vim

If my buffer list looks like this:

```
:ls
  1 %a   "Application/PowerModeServer/test/testTimer.cpp" line 1
  2      "Application/PowerModeServer/test/fakeClient.cpp" line 0
  3      "Application/PowerModeServer/test/fakeVp.cpp" line 0
  7      "Application/PowerModeServer/private/IMsgSender.h" line 0
  9      "Application/PowerModeServer/private/UdpSocket.h" line 0
 17      "Application/PowerModeServer/src/PowerFsm.cpp" line 0
 18      "Application/PowerModeServer/src/lua/src/lfunc.h" line 0
 19      "Application/PowerModeServer/src/lua/src/lmem.h" line 0
 20      "Application/PowerModeServer/src/lua/src/ltable.h" line 0
 41      "Application/PowerModeServer/src/PowerModeServer.cpp" line 0
 42      "Application/PowerModeServer/src/UdpSocket.cpp" line 0
 43      "Application/PowerModeServer/src/Timer.cpp" line 0
```

what's the easiest way to change vim's current working directory to the parent directory of, say, buffer 19?  I'm used to finger-mumbling my way there using:

```
:cd A<TAB>P<TAB>s<TAB>l<TAB>s<TAB>
```

but this requires quite a few keystrokes---especially if the completions are ambiguous. I'd like something more concise, like:

```
:cd ~19
```

Any recommendations?

EDIT: Added mods suggested by ZyX here since I don't have sufficient points to edit Jeet's answer directly:

```
function! CdBufWorkingDir(target)
    if empty(a:target)
        let targetdir = expand("%:p:h")
    else
        if a:target =~# '^\~\d'
            let targetdir = fnamemodify(bufname(str2nr(a:target[1:])), ":p:h")
        else
            let targetdir = a:target
        endif
    endif
    execute "cd ".fnameescape(targetdir)
    echo targetdir
endfunction
command! -nargs=? Cdbuf :call CdBufWorkingDir(<q-args>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this in your "~/.vimrc" (UPDATED in accordance to OP's specs):

```
function! CdBufWorkingDir(...)
    if a:0 == 0
        let l:targetdir = expand("%:p:h")
    else
        if a:1[0] == "~"
            let l:targetdir = fnamemodify( bufname(str2nr(a:1[1:])), ":p:h" )
        else
            let l:targetdir = a:1
        endif
    endif
    execute "cd ". l:targetdir
    echo l:targetdir
endfunction
command! -nargs=* Cdbuf :call CdBufWorkingDir(<q-args>)
```

Then issuing the command with a buffer number preceded by a "~" as an argument (e.g., `:Cdbuf ~3`) will switch the working directory to that buffer's working directory. If the argument is not preceded with "~", it will be treated as a directory path directly to which to change. While the command without an argument will switch the working directory the current buffer's working directory. For robustness, you should add some idiot-checking codes (e.g., what happens when multiple arguments are given?), or handle special cases (e.g., what happens if a string or buffer name is passed, or the file is a symlink).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The 1-arg form (i.e., :Cdbuf 19) didn't work for me for some reason, but the no-arg form put me in the current buffer's directory. Progress! I was really hoping for a 'native' vim solution, though, so I'll hold off on accepting your answer to see what others come up with.  (The ":cd ~19" syntax is short and intuitive.  Too bad it doesn't work!)

Comment: Sorry, bug in the code. The argument needs to be coerced to numeric form. Fixed now. All the more important to either limit yourself to using buffer numbers as arguments, or add in code that checks whether a buffer number is passed or buffer name.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the fix. Vim scripting makes me go cross-eyed. `:-} I found a tip that looks like it'll permit the 'cd ~19' syntax (see http://bit.ly/eNdRKh). What I'd like to do is put ":ccab cd Cd" in my .vimrc, but I'd have to figure out how to make the Cd() function [your Cdbuf() func] do the same thing as the normal ':cd' command if the argument doesn't start with a '~'.  If you're handy enough with Vim scripting to edit your answer so it does that, I'll gladly accept it! Otherwise, I'll try to figure it out over the next 48 hours and post my own answer.

Comment: The power of Vim comes from its flexibility, which in turn comes from its scripting language. If you plan on using Vim for long, and especially if you are fussy about getting it working just so (as are most of us Vimmers), then learning Vimscript will pay for itself. I've modified the script as requested, but I think your choice of a leader prefix ("~") is poor, as it already has a special meaning in the *nix filesystem context and you will never be able to use it that way here (e.g., you cannot use "~/test"). I would use some other character (e.g., "*" or "%").

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I know what you mean about the conflict with 'cd ~foo' in the shell (which I use a *lot*). I was thinking I could restrict the tilde from only being 'special' if it's followed by a number, which wouldn't conflict with my personal usage patterns (I never type 'cd ~19' in the shell). Sounds like a good learning exercise for the OP. :-}

Comment: 1. You forgot to do escaping: `execute "cd ".fnameescape(l:targetDir)`. 2. You do not need `-nargs=*`, use `-nargs=?`. 3. You do not need `...`: `<q-args>` will always produce exactly one argument (so `a:0==0` will never match, use `empty(a:target)` instead). 4. You do not need `l:`: it is the default scope inside functions. 5. Replace `a:1[0]=='~'` with `a:target=~#'^~\d'` (assuming you have replaced `...` with `target`) and your objection (you cannot use `~/test`) will go away.

Comment: @ZyX: Good points all. I'll leave it as an exercise for the OP. Any more modifications and this 30-second code snippet is going to need its own Git repo.

Comment: @Jeet If you want git repo for simple code snippet, look at [gist](https://gist.github.com). Quote: «Gist is a simple way to share snippets and pastes with others. All gists are git repositories, so they are automatically versioned, forkable and usable as a git repository.»

Answer (score 3):

Select the child buffer and type  `:cd %:h|cd ..`

`%` is the current buffer filename, and `:h` is a modifier to extract the directory (the head modifier, see `:help filename-modifiers` for more), the `|` is just to separate commands in the same line.

Answer (score 2):

I use this script http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1325 with this in my .vimrc

```
map <silent> <F3> :call BufferList()<CR>
let g:BufferListWidth = 25     
let g:BufferListMaxWidth = 50
```

Then press f3 and you can just use /filenname + enter

Or you can use `:ls <enter> :buffer BufferNumber <enter>` if you dont want to install the script or map

To make the last one easier add this to your .vimrc `nmap <F3> :ls<CR>:buffer` then you can press f3 and directly the number of the buffer you want.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my intention(?) I don't want to switch buffers, I just want to change vim's current working directory. I guess I don't mind changing the current buffer, too, if it achieves that goal. Is there some setting that causes the cwd to track the current buffer?

Comment: +1 for causing me to find the 'autochdir' option in the docs. Apparently it can cause some plugins to break if left enabled, but it might be useful to temporarily enable/disable it in a mapping like yours.